# Required jars for invoking an EJB on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I have been following the tutorial here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

It has helped a lot with getting a JBoss 7.1.1 project with EJB 3.0 started. I have the server up and running fine with my EAR. The problem I'm having now is with the client. I don't think I have all the required JAR's in my classpath. I'm getting this error: http://pastebin.com/0mMBKjGJ

I found this tutorial: http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1177
which has a list of the JAR's that should be included. Those are not the JAR's in the JBoss 7.1.1 modules folder though. Which JAR's should I be using?

Comment: For JBoss AS 6.1 and earlier the recommended way was to have your remote client also have JBoss I stalled and put its [home]/client dir on its classpath. Note that the client does not need to run JBoss, just have it on its path.